# Validación ajax con framework Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, framework

Buen día a todos.

Estoy levantando un sitio de administración y estoy registrando usuarios, para posteriormente realizar el login respectivo.

Estoy utilizando el Framework Yii2 (2.0.32) PHP 7.2.0 y MySQL

El inconveniente es;
Al registrar un usuario nuevo, hago todo el flujo bien pero al ingresar un usuario nuevo, si este existe me debe indicar el mensaje '*usuario ya existe*'. Para esto, en la carpeta '*models*' tengo el archivo '*formRegistro.php*' en donde tengo las '*rules()*' y la validación del usuario;

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\model;
use app\models\Users;

class formRegistro extends model{
    public $usuario;
    public $password;
    public $password_repeat;

    public function rules() {
        return[
            ['usuario', 'required', 'message'=>'Campo obligatorio'],
            ['usuario', 'user_existe'],
            ['password', 'required', 'message'=>'Campo obligatorio'], 
            ['password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute'=>'password', 'message'=>'Contraseñas no coinciden']
        ];
    }

    public function user_existe($attribute, $params){
        $table=Users::find()->where('usuario=:usuario',[':usuario'=>$this->usuario]);

        if( $table->count() == 1 ){
            $this->addError($attribute, "El usuario ya existe");
        }
    }
}
```

La vista, esta así;

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

$asterix="<strong style='color:red;'>*</strong>";

?>

<h1>Registro de usuario</h1>
<h3 ><?= $mess ?></h3>
<p><?= $asterix ?> Campos obligatorios</p>
<br/>
<?php 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'formregistro',
        'method' => 'POST',
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    ]); 
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group" >
            <?= $form->field($model, 'usuario')->textInput([
            'placeholder'=>'Nombre de usuario',
            'class'=>'form-control'
            ])
            ->label('Usuario '.$asterix); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput([
            'placeholder'=>'Contraseña',
            'class'=>'form-control'
            ])
            ->label('Contraseña '.$asterix); ?>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <?= Html::submitButton('Registrar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary' ]) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y el controlador;

```
public function actionRegistro(){
    $model = new formRegistro;
    $mess=null;

    if ( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Yii::$app->request->isAjax ){
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
        return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
    if( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ){
        if( $model->validate() ){
            $table = new Users;
            $table->usuario=$model->usuario;
            $table->password=  crypt($model->password, Yii::$app->params['salt']);

            if( $table->insert() ){

                $model->usuario=null;
                $model->password=null;
                $model->password_repeat=null;

                $mess="Registro ingresado, redireccionando...<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5; ".Url::toRoute("site/login")."'>";
            }
            else{
                //$model->getErrors();
                $mess="Tenemos ERROR.";
            }

        }
        else{
            $model->getErrors();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('registro', ['model'=>$model, 'mess'=>$mess]);
}

private function randKey($str='',$long=0){
    $key=null;
    $str=str_split($str);
    $start=0;
    $limit=count($str)-1;

    for($r=0; $r<$long; $r++){
        $key.=$str[rand($start, $limit)];
    }
    return $key;
}
```

Y el encabezado del controler;

```
use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use app\models\LoginForm;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\web\Response;

use yii\helpers\Url;
use app\models\formRegistro;
use app\models\Users;
```

No puedo hacer que muestre la validación del usuario.

Estaré atento si se requiere más información.

De antemano, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta quitarle los parámetros de validación en el formulario:

```
'enableClientValidation' => true,
'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
```

Puedes quítalas y prueba de nuevo, debería de funcionar correctamente.

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema del OP? ¿Por que sería está la solución? ¿Me sirve en otras situaciones parecidas?